# Grok "or" around multiple "or" patterns?

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

Is this possible.

I don't have the regex to hand, but in "pseudo" regex i have so far is:

```
(Client_id:IP) | (Cient_id:IPPORT)
```

This works, if it is an IP alone, it matches.  If it an IP:PORT it matches.  But  what I want is:

```
((Client_id:IP) | (Cient_id:IPPORT))  |   ((somethingElse:ANOTHERGROK ) | (soemthingElse:ANOTHERGROK2))
```

I've tried lots of combinations but nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of complex regular expressions in the built-in patterns.  Looking there can sometimes yield good results.

For you, I noticed `[HTTPD_COMMONLOG][1]`, which contains:

> %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)

So you can see how they combine one pattern ("response") with another pattern that contains the "or" ("bytes").